# derived class can be called with base copy constructor

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

in the following code example i have two class, one is derived from the other, they only differ in the output message ("base" vs "derived")

from the main i call both of them, then i use the copy constructor from Base with Derived as a parameter, and it works. even though i don't have a prototype function for such a call :

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base() {
        std::cout << "base default constructor\n";}
    Base(int i) {
        std::cout << "base parameters constructor\n";}
    Base(Base const & src) {
        std::cout << "base copy constructor\n"; *this = src;}
    Base & operator=(Base const & rhs) {
        std::cout << "base assignation operator\n"; return *this;}
    ~Base() {
        std::cout << "base default destructor\n";}
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {
        std::cout << "derived default constructor\n";}
    Derived(int i) {
        std::cout << "derived parameters constructor\n";}
    Derived(Derived const & src) {
        std::cout << "derived copy constructor\n"; *this = src;}
    Derived & operator=(Derived const & rhs) {
        std::cout << "derived assignation operator\n"; return *this;}
    ~Derived() {
        std::cout << "derived default destructor\n";}
};

int main () {

    Base    base1(1); std::cout << "\n";
    Derived derived1(1); std::cout << "\n";
    Base    base2(derived1); std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

and the output :

```
base parameters constructor

base default constructor
derived parameters constructor

base copy constructor
base assignation operator

base default destructor
derived default destructor
base default destructor
base default destructor
```

i was expecting an error like (inversion of output for the call of `Derived derived2(base1);`) :

```
main.cpp:36:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘Base::Base(Derived&)’
   36 |  Base base2(derived1);
      |                     ^
main.cpp:23:2: note: candidate: ‘Base::Base(const Base&)’
   23 |  Base(Base const & src) {
      |  ^~~~
```

why does it works ?

Comment: An object of derived class is implicitly convertible to the base class. That's kinda the point of inheritance - that the derived class can be used wherever the base class is required.

Comment: The Base part of the Derived class can be used in the Base copy constructor.

Comment: oh ok, that's why constructors are not inherited ?

Comment: Constructors are not inherited because the base class' constructor wouldn't know how to initialize any additional members the derived class might have. I'm not sure how this observation is relevant to your original question though.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik when i answered, my thought was : if you could inherit a constructor, you could redefine the constructor, and so you couldn't use the base constructor part of the derived class. But it makes actually no sens to infer this from your answers to my question, since it is exactly what happens with the members of a class : you can redefine them in the derived class, and so when you will want to use the base part of a derived class, it will be the base part as modified by the derived class.

Comment: You lost me, I'm afraid. I have no idea what you are trying to say.

Comment: oh well, it must not be really relevant anyway ;) now i understand better